# How can I create a JavaScript object that is a dictionary in one line of code?

Tags: javascript

I find myself doing this a lot in my app and I'm wondering if there is a way in JavaScript to do what I have below in a simpler way, or specifically, without having to do the `let` declaration first.  It would be cleaner if I could declare the dictionary as a `const`.

My goal is to be able to do lookups by the id instead of having to do a find first, then access the data I need.

```
// actual data array will have a lot more than 2 records
const tagsData = [{id: 1, name: "first one"},{id: 2, name: "second one"}];
  
let tagsDataDictionary = {};
tagsData.forEach(tag => tagsDataDictionary[tag.id] = tag);
```

Comment: Maybe a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) might help? I don’t understand the question all that well, sorry. But hopefully it helps

Comment: Uh, extract it to a function and then do `let foo = toDictionary(arr)`?

Comment: `let tagsDataDictionary = { "1": {id:1, name: "first one"}, "2":{id:2, name: "second one"} }`

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(tagsData.map(tag => [tag.id, tag]))`?

Comment: Are you asking for `const tagsData = { "1": "first one", "2": "second one"};`?

Comment: Why do you want an object with indexes for keys?

Comment: @evolutionxbox a guess but - to be able to lookup objects by the ID.

Comment: Yes, @evolutionxbox, I do want an object indexed by keys.

Comment: Using a Map might be more appropriate?

Comment: @evolutionBox, I want an object referenced by keys so I can easily access values without having to do a find first.

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(
  [{id: 1, name: "first one"},{id: 2, name: "second one"}].reduce((pv, cv) => { pv[cv.id] = cv.name; return pv;}, {})
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine `Object.fromEntries` with `Array.prototype.map` with some object destructuring.

```js
const
  tags = [{ id: 1, name: "first one" }, { id: 2, name: "second one" }],
  dict = Object.fromEntries(tags.map(({ id, ...tag }) => [id, { id, ...tag }]));

console.log(dict);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I think OP just wants to index the objects by `id`, so `tags.map(x => [x.id, x])`

Comment: Side comment: how do you include JavaScript code snippets in text like you have here?

Comment: @Pete hit the button for insert code snippet (to the right of the add image button), when editing.

Comment: @Pete There's a button for that in the editor (looks like `[<>]`). If you go crazy, you can also make them with special HTML comments, but don't ;)

Comment: @Pete [See the guide here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992)

Answer (score 2):

Could be done using reduce:

```js
const tagsData = [{id: 1, name: "first one"},{id: 2, name: "second one"}];
  
const ans2 = tagsData.reduce((acc,x,index) => { acc[index+1] = x; return acc; }, {});
console.log(ans2);
```

But, it is important to point out in your code, you can use `const` instead of `let`:

```js
const tagsData = [{id: 1, name: "first one"},{id: 2, name: "second one"}];
  
const tagsDataDictionary = {};
tagsData.forEach(tag => tagsDataDictionary[tag.id] = tag);

console.log(tagsDataDictionary);
```

`const` variables are not **reassignable**. But you can modify their properties.

Answer (score 2):

This is what `.reduce()` is meant for: combining an array of things into **one** thing. I've seen `.reduce()` abused a lot in js but this is it's actual use case:

```js
const tagsData = [{id: 1, name: "first one"},{id: 2, name: "second one"}];

let tagsDataDictionary = tagsData.reduce(
    (dict,tag) => {
        dict[tag.id] = tag;
        return dict;
    },
    {} // initial value of dict
);

console.log(tagsDataDictionary);
```